# c# сложить попарно элементы двух Listи получить новый List

Tags: c#, linq

есть 2 списка `List<int>`
`1,2,3,4,5`
`2,3,4,5,6`

как сложить с помощью LINQ и получить
`List 3,5,7,8,11`

Comment: `IEnumerable<int> resultList =  list.Select((v, i) => list2[i] + v);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Взято отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2511843/how-do-i-add-two-lists-in-linq-so-addedlistx-listonex-listtwox):

```
var firstList = new List<int>(){1,2,3,4,5};
var secondList = new List<int>(){2,3,4,5,6};
var sumList = firstList.Zip(secondList, (x,y) => x + y).ToList();
```